# How to configure cube.js to use AWS Athena datasource using service account

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-athena, cube.js

Based on official documentation cube.js can connect to AWS Athena and use it as a datasource. Problem is the driver uses AWS access key and secret key which I don't want to use. In my case cube.js is running in Kubernetes (EKS) and I have service account which has permission and I want to use it to access Athena. Is there a way how to configure cube.js to use it and make the connection to Athena working?

I tried to generate access key and secret key from role and token using STS service but I am not able to connect using generated keys.